# Woocommerce update post staus

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I registered few custom post statuses. And i wanna hook it when order received.
i try it by:

```js
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'aa_func_20151609121636',30, 2);
function aa_func_20151609121636($order_id, $posted)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $post_status = null;

if(isset($_POST['yes_its_enq']) && ($_POST['yes_its_enq'] === 'yes')) {
    $post_status = 'wc-gibraenquiry';
} else {
    $post_status ='wc-gibrapending';
}

$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, array( 'post_status' => $post_status ), array( 'ID' => $order_id ) );
}
```

but i failled and post status is wc-processing
What the right hook for it?

Comment: You want to update the status of the order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `update_status` method of WC_Order class to update the status.

Try the following code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'aa_func_20151609121636',30, 2);

function aa_func_20151609121636($order_id, $posted)
{

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if( isset( $posted['yes_its_enq'] ) && ( $posted['yes_its_enq'] === 'yes' ) ) {

        $post_status = 'wc-gibraenquiry';

    } else {

        $post_status ='wc-gibrapending';

    }

    $order->update_status( $post_status ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
But  $_POST['yes_its_enq'] instead $posted['yes_its_enq']  
works for me

Comment: Yes, I checked the hook code and figured that out. so edited my answer :) $posted and $_POST both will work.